# Copy files from HDFS to Amazon S3 using distp and s3a scheme

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

Using Apache Hadoop version 2.7.2 and trying to copy files from HDFS to Amazon S3 using below command.

```
hadoop distcp  hdfs://<<namenode_host>>:9000/user/ubuntu/input/flightdata  s3a://<<bucketid>>
```

Getting below exception using above command.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: s3a://<<bucketid>>.distcp.tmp.attempt_1462460298670_0004_m_000001_0
```

Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Have you followed guidelines on this page: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to go from HDFS to S3 - I have done it before using syntax like the following, running it from a HDFS cluster:

distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key=... -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=...  /user/vagrant/bigdata s3a://mytestbucket/bigdata

It you run your command like this, does it work:

hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode_host:9000/user/ubuntu/input/flightdata  s3a://bucketid/flightdata

From the exception, it looks like it is expecting a 'folder' to put the data in, as opposed to the root of the bucket.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. It was expecting folder to put the data in as opposed to bucket root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide AWS credentials in order to successfully transfer files TO/FROM HDFS and S3.

You can pass the access_key_id and secret parameters as shown by @stephen above but you should use a [credential provider](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CredentialProviderAPI.html) api for production use where you can manage your credentials without passing them around in individual commands.

Ref: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CredentialProviderAPI.html

Secondly you do not need to specify "hdfs" protocol. An absolute hdfs path is sufficient.